# How do i send a mass email individually using Spring java?

Tags: java, spring, email

I want to send an email to a group of several contacts. I don't want to put all the email addresses in the `setTo(String[] contacts)` field, because I don't want that they can see each other. I don't want to put all the email addresses in the `setBcc(String[] contacts)` field neither, because then they can't even see their own email.

I want to send the email out so that each contact sees only their own email address in the "TO" field. How can I do that? Is there a well-known method or approach? Or should I send an email to each contact using a loop? For example, something like this:
 `for (String oneContact : stringArrayOfRecipients){
    sendEmail(oneContact, message);
}`

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that you will have to use a loop to do that.

SMTP protocol, which is used by the mail servers to deliver mail, has no mechanism to do what you want to do.
In addition, the To property in the email is part of the message body, which can be set to any arbitrary string.

The problem with looping through a mailing list like you describe, is that your emails will look like spam.  (A lot of identical messages, send to a lot of users)  They may get flagged because of that.

Alternatively, you may be able to set the To field to a generic address such as "Mailing List", and use Bcc for the recipients.

Comment: Could you detail explain about a generic address such as "Mailing List" or cause a small sample what to write in the `To` field

Comment: I would use something like:
    String mailingListEmail = "Mailing List <list@mycompany.com";
then use that as your setTo email address.

Comment: Generally, the idea is - when the user gets an email, they will see that it is sent to a mailing list.  You can also use something like "NO-REPLY" as the setTo address, or use some generic, or catch-all email address.  If, for some reason, the recipient sends an email to that address, you can process it as appropriate.